# Why is pausing every request, then immediatly continuing it faster than doing nothing at all in playwright?

Tags: google-chrome, playwright, cdp

I am using `Page.route` to intercept all requests, and add the auth header to only specific request URLs. I decided to test to see if there was a performance impact on how long it took the page to get to "networkidle" between setting the header indiscriminately (ie `page.set_extra_http_headers`) and intercepting each request before it was sent out. To my surprise, I found that intercepting requests before they were sent was measurably faster on real web pages, and drastically faster in some other scenarios:

```
type=request interception (passthrough) n= 30 std_dev=0.07077  mean=2.66928
type=normal                             n= 30 std_dev=0.24912  mean=12.10215
```

Opening my pathological URL in my own installation of Chrome, I observed a time right in the the range of type=normal. I'm wondering why this is. Chrome seems to be throttling the number of concurrent requests. The same page in Firefox reaches a network idle state very quickly. I observed this with Playwright 1.40.0 (latest), as well as some earlier versions.

This is how I'm routing the requests:

```py
async def passthrough(route: Route, req: Request):
    await route.continue_()
await page.route("*", passthrough)
```

Full test code [here](https://gist.github.com/Mattwmaster58/5568e14548b76de68eda0a51bc1b786e)

Test server code:

```py
import asyncio
import random

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
async def ping():
    # if omitted, there is still a measurable difference, but it's not as large
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random() / 25)
    return "pong"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Test page HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <script>
        function sendRequests() {
            for (let i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
                fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/ping', { method: 'GET' })
                    .then(response => console.log(`Request ${i}: ${response.status}`))
                    .catch(error => console.error(`Request ${i}: ${error.message}`));
            }
        }
        sendRequests();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure I have an answer but random numbers in benchmarks seems highly suspect. Also, make sure there's no caching going on.

Comment: The effect is still there without a random delay. I have tested this over thousands of trials. page.route will automatically turn off caching as well. I tested to see if the difference was from that but found turning off caching alone to be negligibly different than normal operation. The browser is closed between each trial.

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i <= 500; i++) fetch(same URL)` doesn't give a bunch of 304s? Do you have an actual application scenario where the apparent difference is significant enough to be relevant, or is this a piece of trivia/curiosity?

Comment: No 304s, Flask doesn't do that by default. The effect has been observed loading real world web pages, about 5% slower. I'm working on a service that scans 10's of millions of pages, so it might add up. It would be nice to save 5% :)